# Make transition stable after event occur

Tags: css

How can i make the transition still occur after the event is removed!
I want to resize div height when hover to be smaller, but I want the size to still smaller even when I remove hover from the div.

```
#header{
background-color: red;
height:300px;
width:100%;
-moz-transition:height 500ms linear;
-webkit-transition:height 500ms linear;
-o-transition:height 500ms linear;
-ms-transition:height 500ms linear;
transition:height 500ms linear;
}

#header:hover{
height:100px;
}
```

I want the div to have 100px height after the mouse is out, can I make it using only css, or I have to use jQuery to change the class or sth like that?

Comment: Your question is a little confusing.  You want to have an initial state, then a hover, then an after hover state?  You would need JavaScript for that.  If I'm misunderstanding you, please add some more information.

Comment: I wonder to know if I can make the transition still even the mouse out of the source using CSS3 only, but it seems I can't make it without using js...

Comment: "mouse out of the source"  <-- Can you try explaining that differently?  By "mouse" you mean the mouse cursor?  By "source" you mean `#header`?

Comment: Yes I mean when I move the mouse cursor out of the header.

Comment: I see you accepted Nate's answer.  If that means you have some working code, could you share it with us?  It might help someone that has the same problem in the future.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make a hover "stick" with just CSS. You would need to add a class or inline style with Javascript to maintain the appearance.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a hover "stick" with just CSS.

```
@keyframes hover {
  0% {
    // normal styles
  }
  100% {
    // hover styles
  }
}

.class {
  animation-name: hover;
  animation-duration: 350ms;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
  animation-play-state: paused;      
}

.class:hover {
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-play-state: running;
}
```

See http://cdpn.io/GLjpK and http://lea.verou.me/2014/01/smooth-state-animations-with-animation-play-state/.